# VS2015 Closing Windows Form not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I have VS2015 Windows Form, and whenever I click X to close application, it prompts me to close it or not. When I press No, then the pop up window would close. However, when I press Yes, it pops up another same window, and asks me to close it or not.

How can I solve this issue? I want to close my form at first popup.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            const string closemsg = "Do you really want to close the program?";
            const string exit = "Exit";

            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(closemsg, exit, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `Application.Exit();` ? What if you just do nothing and return leaving `e.Cancel` to false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.
**Make remove Application.Exit();**

Application.Exit() generates the FormClosing event.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{ 
    const string closemsg = "Do you really want to close the program?";
    const string exit = "Exit";

    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(closemsg, exit, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //Remove Application.Exit();
        //Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh! I forgot about that :P Here have a +1

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I press Yes, it pops up another same window, and asks me to close it or not.

The reason is because your `Form1_FormClosing` will be called again.  Try setting a `_isExiting` flag that you can test upon entry.

Try this:

```
bool _isExiting;

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isExiting) 
    {
        // whoops, been here already, time to go!
        return;
    }

    const string closemsg = "Do you really want to close the program?";
    const string exit = "Exit";

    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show(closemsg, exit, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        _isExiting=true; // set flag here so we don't repeat this exercise again
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```